# Play Framework db.play.JPA

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

Okay. I am having big confusion with Play Framework. (Do they update their tutorial and documentation as often as their products?). I am trying to do the tutorial for CRUD app, and I am using JPA instead of Ebean (because the last one does not work, but, as appeared, the first either). 
Compiler says, it can not find class Model.

Internet offers to get the right dependencies and I already tried a lot of them. But I can't get the right one. Can anyone help me how to make this easiest thing work?

Here are my routes:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
POST    /person               controllers.Application.addPerson()
```

Here are the app configuration, that were oncommented

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
```

built.sbt dependences:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  Jdbc, 
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.5.Final"
  )
```

Application.java:

```
package controllers;

import models.Person;
import play.*;
import play.data.Form;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;
public class Application extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

    public Result addPerson(){
        Person person = Form.form(Person.class).bindFromRequest().get();
        person.save();
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }

}
```

And models Person.java:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
 import play.db.jpa.*;

@Entity 
public class Person extends Model{
    @Id
    public String id;
    public String name;


}
```

Comment: Why do you extend `Person` from `play.db.ebean.Model`? Is there a need even if you don't use Ebean but JPA? Did you try to use `import play.db.ebean.Model;`?

Comment: Yes, I tried (plus adding dependencies for ebean and stuff, compiler would say that play.db.ebean does not exist

Comment: and, actually, I would prefer to do it with JPA, but firstly tried Ebean because it was in playframework tutorial

Comment: And what's your current target? To get it running with Ebean **or** to get it running with JPA? If it's the latter then have you tried **not** to extend from `play.db.ebean.Model`?

Comment: With JPA. How should I extend then?

Comment: JPA doesn't need the Entities to extend from anything (`@Entity` is sufficient). But I don't know the *Play Framework* if there are other reasons than db handling to extend Entity from `Model`.

Comment: PlayFramework documentation says "if you make one of your JPA entities extend the play.db.jpa.Model class, it will give you a lot of helper methods to simplify the JPA access". As you are the only answering, could we move to chat?

Answer (score 0):

By using JPA without Ebean it should be like described [here](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaJPA#Using-the-play.db.jpa.JPA-helper)
For example (haven't tested actually) like fallowing code:

```
public Result addPerson(){
    Person person = Form.form(Person.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    EntityManager em = JPA.em();
    em.persist(person);
    em.flush();
    return redirect(routes.Application.index());
}
```

and model will look similar to that:

```
@Entity 
public class Person
{

    private long id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```